# Input formatted date and time in Swing to get nodes using GET REST

Tags: java, swing, url, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am required to input start time and end time and in swing java that I will further send to a URL to get some selected nodes created in this time using `GET REST` call. 
`URL` is:

```
http://wisekar.iitd.ernet.in/active/api_resources.php/method/mynode
    ?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
    &startTime=START_TIME[Optional]
    &endTime=END_TIME[Optional]en
```

The website will take take the input (time stamps) as they are given in the image.

Screenshot Of my window

[image]

Now my code is here:

```
class Algorithm extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static String ENDPOINT =
            "http://wisekar.iitd.ernet.in/active/api_"
            + "resources.php/method/mynode.json?key=api_key";

    Algorithm() {
       // label1 = new JLabel();.....

        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2));
        //adding in panel label1,text1 ... 
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        SUBMIT.addActionListener(this);
        setTitle("Optimal Travel Route");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
            //String value1 = text1.getText();..

            URL url = new URL(ENDPOINT + "&datasetId=" + value3
                    + "&startTime=" + value1 + "&endTime=" + value2);
            System.out.println(url);
            HttpURLConnection httpCon;
            httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpCon.setDoInput(true);
            System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpCon.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Algorithm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

class AlgorithmDemo {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {
            Algorithm frame = new Algorithm();
            frame.setSize(450, 200);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything; I have commented it. Using this code, I am getting the nodes when I am typing the generated URL in the browser, but it is not giving the result on the console when I am printing. What is wrong in my code? Can someone tell me how should date and time should be passed to the GET. Please help. When I only input the data set ID, it gives me all the nodes of that data set ID. According to me, there is some problem in passing the time stamps.

Comment: So you're not getting the nodes, what are you actually getting?

Comment: I have some nodes on that website that will be shown when the URL succeed and the information associated with the nodes will be shown like its longitude, latitude ,name e.t.c in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately when I ran a quick test I got an unauthorized response.
But it looks like the issue is the string is not url safe.
Yo need to ensure your spaces are converted to %20.
This will also be why it works using and browser as the browser address bar will do this for you behind the scenes.
If you use:

```
String urlSafeValue1 = URLEncoder.encode(value1, "UTF-8");
String urlSafeValue2 = URLEncoder.encode(value2, "UTF-8");
String urlSafeValue3 = URLEncoder.encode(value3, "UTF-8");
```

The arguments will be made url safe.

Answer (score 1):

try this my friend ...

```
String httpURL = ENDPOINT + URLEncoder.encode("&datasetId=" + value3
                 + "&startTime=" + value1 + "&endTime=" + value2, "UTF-8");
URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(httpURL).openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your time stamps are on the format in the screenshot, they contain spaces which must be escaped in URLs. Try

```
value1 = value1.replaceAll(" ", "+");
```

and similarly for `value2` before constructing the URL.

Comment: No the website will take the input as entered. It should include the spaces which get replaced by %20 in the URL

Comment: No, the `URL` will not do that for you. If you're typing the URL into a browser, _it_ will do this for you, but as far as `java.net.URL`, you will have to do this yourself.

Comment: The website will take the i/p as shown . it includes the space than why should I remove the spaces in the i/p time stamp .Can you explain.